# How can I change the category to the page in the articles

Tags: wordpress

How can I change the category to the page in the articles?

I have all categories no index.

I get clicks on it which is causing me a problem.

I want to change the category in the article to the interested page.

Comment: You should ask in [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) – and try to use some punctuation and mind the double text, I thought I was having a stroke… :P

Comment: Explain your question/issue with enough details which can help others to write an answer.